# Duplicate Symbols and Linker command failed

Tags: build, xcode15

Since I updated to Xcode 15.0 and I try to run the app in the simulator or an actual device, I get these two errors.  The build ran clean before.

Clicking on them doesn't show where the error is occurring.

[image]

I have tried the other threads recommendations to no avail.  I do not know how to use the -v to see invocation either.

I have deleted the deriveddata folder and run the "cmd+shift+K" I have checked for duplicate file names and there are no test targets just the app. I have not renamed it either.

Where should I go from here?